# Why Do My Objects Render Without Materials? [Ceramic]

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, objects, light

So, I'm trying to make some ceramic (copied some nodes from online) objects for a practice project, but I can't get it to show up when Rendering. I tried to simplify, just apply it to a sphere, but I still can't get it to work. 
I'm still pretty new so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Blender Setup]

Comment: It looks like your scene doesn't have enough lighting to make your sphere shine. I would suggest using an HDRi or adding some more lights to your scene.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashutosh said, you need to put some light sources in your scene so that you can see the glossiness of your object. If I create a floor and put two planes with an *Emission* shader material, it seems like your nodes organization works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding! So I understand where I went wrong, but shouldn't the sphere be coloured white? I thought colour information is included with material information. Or do I also need a texture (or something else)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, your sphere is colored white, if you look at your nodes your Subsurface Scattering node, your Diffuse node and your Glossy node are white. It appears grey on my screenshot because the emission strength of my planes is low.

Comment: ... it also appears darker because the *environment color* is set to a dark grey @moonboots.